# Code Igniter url segment illegal characters replace with '-'

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

In code igniter I need to replace illegal characters of 4th segment with '-', for example

http://example.com/groups/index/26/this-is-a-test

works fine and

http://example.com/groups/index/26/this-is-a-test!!!

this not working and show 'The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." error message. I need to replace ! or any other disallowed characters with '-'. Can you please give me a solution for this?

Comment: I used .htaccess mod_rewrite to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the URI class, get the current URI string, remove the illegal chars, then redirect to the new string.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

But I dont understand why people are going to the wrong URL in the first place? That seems like a bad idea in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with a Regex to strip your string, but you might also look at the `url_title` function.

From the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
$title = "What's wrong with CSS?";

$url_title = url_title($title); // Produces: Whats-wrong-with-CSS
```